# How to create a rank-based column based on multiple column conditions in r dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, multiple-columns, cumsum

I have a dataframe that contains 3 columns and I want to create 4th column based on values given in other columns . For creating new_rank column , we start with 1 as a starting point for all users and increase the succeeding rank value by 1 when matric_1 is more than 15 and matric_2 is more than 20..

I feel I need to use cumsum function in r , but am struggling with ifelse conditions . Code for dataframe is given below

```
df<-data.frame(user_id=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"),matric_1=c(10,23,4,5,17,5,40,1,2,18,19,5,18,2,19,2),matric_2=c(10,25,10,13,21,10,7,3,4,22,21,4,23,4,21,4),new_rank=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3))


User_id matric_1    matric_2    new_rank
a      10%  10%    1
a      23%  25%    1
a      4%   10%    2
a      5%   13%    2
b      17%  21%    1
b      5%   10%    2
b      40%  7%     2
c      1%   3%     1
c      2%   4%     1
c      18%  22%    1
c      19%  21%    2
c      5%   6%     3
d      18%  23%    1
d      2%   4%     2
d      19%  21%    2
d      2%   4%     3
```

Comment: Where is your code? Why is the value for `new_rank` in the line following the instance of high `matric_x` values (shouldn't it be "metric"?)? Is the condition *and* (as you write) or is it *or*? Just confirming, as the output you show is not clear for the last line of User b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'user_id', create the 'new_rank1' by taking the `lag` of the `cumsum` of the logical `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>% 
   mutate(new_rank1 = lag(cumsum(matric_1 > 15 & matric_2 > 20) + 1, default = 1))
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups: user_id [4]
#   user_id matric_1 matric_2 new_rank new_rank1
#   <fctr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 a          10.0     10.0      1.00      1.00
# 2 a          23.0     25.0      1.00      1.00
# 3 a           4.00    10.0      2.00      2.00
# 4 a           5.00    13.0      2.00      2.00
# 5 b          17.0     21.0      1.00      1.00
# 6 b           5.00    10.0      2.00      2.00
# 7 b          40.0      7.00     2.00      2.00
# 8 c           1.00     3.00     1.00      1.00
# 9 c           2.00     4.00     1.00      1.00
#10 c          18.0     22.0      1.00      1.00
#11 c          19.0     21.0      2.00      2.00
#12 c           5.00     4.00     3.00      3.00
#13 d          18.0     23.0      1.00      1.00
#14 d           2.00     4.00     2.00      2.00
#15 d          19.0     21.0      2.00      2.00
#16 d           2.00     4.00     3.00      3.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @akrun solution, but using `data.table` package

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)
df[, rank := shift( x = cumsum(matric_1 > 15 & matric_2 > 20) + 1,
                    fill = 1, 
                    type = "lag" ), 
   by = user_id]
df
#    user_id matric_1 matric_2 new_rank rank
# 1:       a       10       10        1    1
# 2:       a       23       25        1    1
# 3:       a        4       10        2    2
# 4:       a        5       13        2    2
# 5:       b       17       21        1    1
# 6:       b        5       10        2    2
# 7:       b       40        7        2    2
# 8:       c        1        3        1    1
# 9:       c        2        4        1    1
# 10:       c       18       22        1    1
# 11:       c       19       21        2    2
# 12:       c        5        4        3    3
# 13:       d       18       23        1    1
# 14:       d        2        4        2    2
# 15:       d       19       21        2    2
# 16:       d        2        4        3    3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"),matric_1=c(10,23,4,5,17,5,40,1,2,18,19,5,18,2,19,2),matric_2=c(10,25,10,13,21,10,7,3,4,22,21,4,23,4,21,4),new_rank=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3))
```